# Lecture 10 Twitter Table View: Content-assist doesn't work for twitter class in Xcode

Tags: xcode, content-assist, cs193p

I'm trying to make my own twitter table view from scratch following the demo. However it is very strange that after I imported the Twitter package to the project, I can see that for example Tweet class gets syntx highlight, but content assist does not work for, for example, TwitterRequest class.

For example, when I type in the viewDidLoad() function:

`let request = TwitterRequest(s`

it only show me "self"

and later when I type

```
request.
```

it doesn't show anything. Control+space shows "no completion".

Does anyone know what is wrong with my xCode?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... myself.

From Xcode, Under menu Window, go to
Xcode Organizer -> Projects -> (Your Project) -> Delete Derived Data

Unlike others are saying on StackOverflow that you don't need to restart Xcode if you do like this, I have to restart Xcode to make it work.